# The horizontal side length of one of four small rectangle is a and the vertical side length is b. Verification: a + b = 1.

Tags: geometry

A square ABCD with a side length of 1 is divided into five small rectangles, four of which have the same area. The horizontal side length of one of four small rectangle is a and the vertical side length is b. Verification: a + b = 1.

Comment: @Matteo reconsider.  If $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=\frac{1}{4}$ then the square wouldn't have sidelength $1$ would it?

Comment: Four rectangles have the same area only.

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example:

[image]

The four rectangles are $1 \times \frac{1}{6}$

Answer (score 0):

A square ABCD with a side length of $~1~$ is divided into five small rectangles, four of which have the same area. The horizontal side length of one of four small rectangle is $~a~$ and the vertical side length is $~b~$.

Verification: $~a + b = 1~$.

[image]

Comment: See my answer in reference to this graph.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not true in general.

For example you may divide the base of square into four equal segments of $a=1/4$ and let $b=1/3$ or any other positive number less than $1$ and different from $3/4$

Then you have the partition of you square with $a+b\ne 1$

Answer (score 0):

From the graph, I have: $4ab+(1-2b)^2=1$. Solving for $a+b$, I obtain: $$4a+4b-4=0$$ and so $a+b=1$.

Comment: we do not know four rectangles are equivalent.They have the same area only.

Comment: I refer to the graph above.